# Is DiffSuppressFunc or being more restrictive when saving to TF state is preferable in Terraform SDKv2?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

context: I'm adding a new resource to TF Provider (using SDKv2) with roughly the following schema:

```
resource "player" "football" {
   type = "FOOTBALL"
   ...
   config = {
     "dribbling"  = "50"
     "speed"     = "90"
     "position"  = "GOALKEEPER"
   }
}
```

that I represent as:

```
"config": {
    Type: schema.TypeMap,
    Elem: &schema.Schema{
        Type: schema.TypeString,
    },
    Required:    true,
    ForceNew:    true,
},
```

The important detail here for different *palyer* instances' types there'll be a different set of required attributes (`dribbling, speed, position` for *football* and `height, can_dunk, arm_span` for *basketball*) -- all players share the same API endpoint so I introduced just one resource to cover them all.

I'd like to support the ability of importing players and apparently `READ` response includes a bunch of fields that are optional on create (and I suspect most of the users won't have them in Terraform configuration file) which results in the fact that I've got a state difference when saving the whole config like:

```
d.Set("config", player.GetConfig()) # GetConfig includes a bunch of new attributes (optional on a create or even computed)
```

So I've got a question: which of the following 2 options is preferable:

1. Implement `DiffSuppressFunc` for a `config` attribute where I'll be ignoring these optional fields (the downside is I'll have an implicit drift between `main.tf` and TF state file).
2. Be more restrictive when writing configs to TF state file:

```
instead of 
d.Set("config", player.GetConfig())
# filtered config will match config in main.tf
filteredConfig = ...
d.Set("config", filteredConfig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some other Terraform providers that deal with similar situations (where a particular argument has a mixture of configuration-provided and remote-system-provided nested values), the resource type implementation takes a compromise position of effectively exposing the same data in two different attributes, where one of them represents what the user configured and the other represents the full data returned by the remote system. For example, you might have `config` to be set in the configuration, and `expanded_config` representing the full set of elements the server decided.

There is a challenge with that approach in that you'll probably need a special rule in your `Read` function to somehow decide if a change you detect in the remote system constitutes "drift" relative to the configuration or if it's just an additional element added by the server.

From what you described it seems like the rule could be that any key that's present in `config` in the prior state (that is, the values visible to `d.Get` inside `Read` before you call `d.Set`) would have its value overwritten by what the server returned, but any keys that were not present before are ignored entirely. This would create the effect then that any key the author specified in the configuration is considered "managed by Terraform" while any other key is only read by Terraform and not directly managed.

If you adopt that strategy then it's worth keeping in mind what will happen in a situation where the user has changed the configuration to include a new key or to remove a previously-present key. The `Read` operation is in terms of the previous state rather than the configuration, so that function will see the keys that were present at the end of the last apply, not the keys currently present in the configuration. In particular this means that if an author adds a new key that the server was already tracking then it will appear in the subsequent plan as being added, even though it might technically be more appropriate to show it as an in-place update `~` or a no-op. This is an example of the compromises we sometimes need to make in order to adapt remote APIs to fit within Terraform's model of resource instances.